# Disable form submissions feature from capturing data in keen io

Tags: form-submit, form-data, keen-io

We are currently using keen.io auto collector in our platform, this automatically collects form submissions. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Remove this feature from collecting form data??

Answer (score 0):

You can find the configuration options for [Keen.io's](https://keen.io) web auto collector within the [keen-tracking.js](https://github.com/keen/keen-tracking.js) repository on GitHub in the docs folder.

[auto collector configuration](https://github.com/keen/keen-tracking.js/blob/master/docs/auto-tracking.md#configuration-options)

You want to pass the value for the recordFormSubmits property to *false* when calling the function to initialize the auto collector tracking object like this.

```
  const client = new KeenTracking({
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  writeKey: 'YOUR_WRITE_KEY'
  });

  client.initAutoTracking({
    recordFormSubmits: true,    
  });
```

Take a look at the docs. There are a lot of options for customization in implementing tracking solutions for that library. If you need any more assistance with Keen.io, please feel free to reach out to me. I am happy to assist.